# INVALID_REQUEST error in pull taskqueues

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm using a pull queue in Appengine for Go and while locally leasing tasks worked just fine, when I deployed my code, the call to taskqueue.Lease gave me this error:

`API error 13 (taskqueue: INVALID_REQUEST)`

My lease call was:

`tasks, err := taskqueue.Lease(ctx, 100, "pullqueue", 60)`

And it has happened no matter what parameters I pass in, like parameters for a blank queue name. Has anyone else gotten this error? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm in my real code I was leasing 2000 tasks but the max I can lease is actually 1000.